# Hibernate LockModes/LockOptions

Tags: java, hibernate

I am going through Hibernate Documentation an came across the `LockModes`. Are these same as `Isolation levels` that we use for database? How are they different from `Isolation levels`?

I am trying a simple example and observed that the hibernate is hitting the database when I use session.load() method itself instead of hitting the DB when I call some methods on the loaded object.

```
session.beginTransaction(); //Line 1
DomesticCat d1 = (DomesticCat)session.load(DomesticCat.class, 1L,LockOptions.UPGRADE); //Line 2
d1.meow(); //Line 3
session.getTransaction().commit(); //Line 4
```

I observed that hibernate hits the database at line 2 itself, please tell me why it happens like that? If I remove the LockOptions parameter then the DB hit is made on `Line 3` instead of `Line 2`

The [API for LockOptions](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/api/org/hibernate/LockOptions.html#READ) gives very little details on what they are:

> READ represents LockMode.READ (timeout + scope do not apply)

What does it mean that `timeout + scope do not apply`?

> UPGRADE represents LockMode.UPGRADE (will wait forever for lock and
>   scope of false meaning only entity is locked)

When we should use UPGRADE? what it means that `scope of false meaning only entity is locked`?

May be these are basic questions for experienced guys, please help me in understanding the concept here.

Thanks for looking my post.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Isolation Levels affect what you see.

Lock Modes affect what you are allowed to do.

The normal settings for hibernate are read-committed isolation and optimistic locks.

With optimistic locking, when two people try to edit the same data at the same time, the second one to commit will get an exception.

1. User 1 loads DomesticCat#1066 without upgrade lock.
2. User 2 loads DomesticCat#1066 without upgrade lock.
3. User 2 changes cat's name and commits.
4. User 1 changes cat's birthday, attempts to commit, an exception is thrown.

If pessimistic locks are in use, by selecting LockMode UPGRADE, then nobody else will be allowed to alter the data until the person who asked for the Lock UPGRADE releases it.

1. User 1 loads DomesticCat#1066 *with* upgrade lock.
2. User 2 loads DomesticCat#1066 without upgrade lock.
3. User 2 changes cat's name and attempts to commit.  This operation is not allowed until User 1 releases the lock, so the database blocks and User 2's session sits and waits.
4. User 1 changes cat's birthday, commits.
5. User 2's update can now try to commit, but since they used optimistic locking now they will be the one who sees an exception.

The reason the query has to be executed as soon as you load when you upgrade is that it's implemented using the `select ... for update` statement and hibernate promises you that you'll have the lock when that method returns, so it has to execute the statement right away.  When you don't need to hold the lock, hibernate can be lazy and defer loading the data until you show that you actually do need it.

Generally you upgrade the lock level when you have an operation that *must* complete regardless of what other people are doing.  For example, when it's users, you can just show them the error and they can adjust their work and try again.  But if the updates are being made by a messaging server or background process, handling exceptions and trying again can be very complicated, so it might be better to just lock the record so you can be sure your update goes in.

Comment: Thanks a lot Affe for a detailed, simple and very clear explanation.

Comment: can you please tell me what does it mean `timeout + scope do not apply` and another one for `scope of false meaning only entity is locked`?

Comment: `timeout` does not apply to read locks.because the method used to implement the lock has no risk of being forced to wait.  Scope does not apply to read locks because the definition of scope says so.  Scope is false means you only lock DomesticCat.  If scope were true, you would also lock, for example, all of its Kittens any time you lock the DomesticCat.  This is dangerous in a RDBMS and must be done with care to avoid deadlocks.

Comment: @Affe Its a great explanation, the hibernate api doc does not mention a detail on this. May I please request you to share supporting reference doc.

Comment: +1 Right after precious explaining line "Isolation Levels affect what you see.
Lock Modes affect what you are allowed to do."

Answer (score 1):

UPGRADE means that you want to modify the loaded object and you don't want any other process to change it while you're in the process.

It's an odd combination to use load with UPGRADE, because load is generally used just to have reference to the object to be able to use it while modifying some other object. e.g.

`DomesticCat kitten = (DomesticCat)session.get(DomesticCat.class, 2L);
kitten.setParent(d1);`

That is why if you use a load, Hibernate will only load it if you start referencing properties.