# Waiting for transaction commint. Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Tags: java, hibernate

1) I am doing some operations on my object.

2) Meanwhile other thread wants to do simple change on the same object.

Both operations 1 and 2 must be done.

I know why this error occurs and what is OptimisticLock and version in Hibernate. I want to use LockMode or something like that to make 2) wait until 1) transaction commits. How to do that? What LockMode use for loading object in 1) and which in 2) before saving them?

Comment: `UPGRADE`. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/21031444/5221149

Comment: Thank u ;) I will read it. Still one more question. In 1) transaction I would load my object using UPGRADE but there are some methods that loads this object againg without UPGRADE, since I am still on big transaction, is it OK?